# Use Groovy Script to Parse a Query String in Which Data Are Embedded in the Path

Tags: groovy, soapui

thanks for your time and help in advance.

I am using soapUI mock service and trying to write Groovy script.  The request query URL I receive looks like:

```
 http://server:port/readwrapper/v1/historicalData/medicalHistory/STR/888888_2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10012.100001.206_h0102a3727570b14038b349136f2a5fd58e0102
```

and what I am trying to extract from this URL are

1. 2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10012.100001.206 which is the communityID
2. h0102a3727570b14038b349136f2a5fd58e0102 which is the document ID

All I am able to code in Groovy is:

```
def reqStr = mockRequest.getHttpRequest().getQueryString()
```

and I do not know how to proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it works (I don't use SoapUI), but you could try:

```
def (cid,did) = mockRequest.httpRequest
                           .requestURI
                           .tokenize( '/' )
                           .last()
                           .tokenize( '_' )
                           .drop( 1 )
```

Of if the version of Groovy SoapUI uses doesn't support `drop`:

```
def (cid,did) = mockRequest.httpRequest
                           .requestURI
                           .tokenize( '/' )
                           .last()
                           .tokenize( '_' )[ 1..-1 ]
```

And if it doesn't support multiple assignment, then:

```
def parts = mockRequest.httpRequest
                       .requestURI
                       .tokenize( '/' )
                       .last()
                       .tokenize( '_' )[ 1..-1 ]
def cid = parts[ 0 ]
def did = parts[ 1 ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the code. If you do not mind helping me a little more ...

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the code. If you do not mind helping me a little more ...  if the string is R_H_D and we use tokenize('_') to parse that string. Does [-1] mean the last one in that string, which is "D"?  Which index is the first one "R" in that string?  And which index is the second one "H" in that string?  Thank you.